# Can't we use a GET to create a new resource in REST instead of a PUT?

Tags: rest, api-design, endpoint

I am a newbie to REST web services. I have been going through a tutorial, where it is described that

1. GET is used to provide a read only access to a resource
2. PUT is used to create a new resource
3. DELETE is used to remove a resource
4. POST is used to update/create a resource

and the list goes on.

So if we are passing the arguments/parameters to the service to process something, why cant we implement an update action using a GET or a delete action using a GET or POST. How is the service going to control an action that's going to happen in the back end ?

Comment: The list doesn't go on that much really, all you're missing is patch.

Comment: *How is the service going to control an action*... That's up to the person who writes the service code and function handler

Comment: There is certain semantics attached to these methods in the HTTP standard. They differ for example in caching or retry behaviour. If you use the wrong method, things are going to break sooner or later.

Comment: @cricket_007 so can I use a POST to actually delete something in the back end ?  Is it possible ?

Comment: Not sure why my question has been down voted. I have asked for references and I don't know what's wrong in that

Comment: Yes, you can. Again, it's up to the developer of the API.

Comment: Hi All..I was really a newbie at the time I asked this question. Now I am working on REST APIs for 3 years or more and I know how things work !! Thanks to community for guiding me then :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find lists of popular API's all over the place.

https://webdam.com/blog/top-10-web-apis_bridging-todays-technology/
http://www.computersciencezone.org/50-most-useful-apis-for-developers/

Think in terms of facebook: Get Feed, Put Status, Post New Profile Picture, Delete Comment, Patch Join Group.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.api

Comment: Thanks..I will refer the link you have provided